# outlook vba "out of office" - how to query the presence of a receiver?

Tags: vba, outlook

By the helpful answers from Dmitry Streblechenko I am now able to resolve a receiver and ask if the e-mail is correct. But can someone help me, how to use the expression [AutoResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipient-autoresponse-property-outlook#see-also)? Unfortunately, I could not find anything helpful after my research what could me explain how to use it! But it sounds like exactly what I need... I try to start an if query, which should ask if an automatic answer exists. if so, it should be saved in the tab next to the searched receiver. I want to formate this saved automessage to get the date when the receiver comes back to office. But i have no idea how to use AutoResponse for an if query.

Enclosed as desired, a code excerpt:

```
Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient    
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

myItem.Assign

Set myDelegate = myItem.Recipients.Add(strMail)

myDelegate.Resolve

If myDelegate.Resolved Then

            Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set objMail = objApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Def of objMail like objMail.Subject, objMail.BodyFormat, objMail.HTMLBody ...

            objMail.Display

            Set objApp = Nothing
            Set objMail = Nothing

    Else
        Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "is not resolved"

    End If
```

Comment: We can *help you* with this, but we won't do it *for you*. You need to show what you've tried and we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! The problem is i do not know what i can searching for for the out of office problem. I have not the problem with the template (like to put variables like a name from the tab) but to presence of a receiver i cannot find anything what brings me to the solution... so i have to send all my mails per hand and control if there a in vacation^^

Comment: Could you add more clarity to your question as well? Maybe attach an image of your spreadsheet or any code you already have. Be more detailed on what your exact issue is. Kinda stated above, "I need this.." or "Can I do that.." questions aren't well received here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I update my question and hope it´s better now?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Recipient object using `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` passing the name or address or the person, call `Recipient.Resolve`, call `Recipient.FreeBusy`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipient-freebusy-method-outlook